# Logger configuration safety warning by SonarQube

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, logging, sonarqube

After implementing logging functionality in a microservice, I sent the code thought a SonarQube code-check. SonarQube keeps warning me about a safety issues regarding loggers. I tried several things to resolve it, including not putting the logger in DEBUG mode and specifying the logger configuration in a separate file instead of hardcoding it. 
I would like to know if the following logging implementation is safe and if not, how this should be done in a secure way.

Link to raised issue: https://rules.sonarsource.com/python/RSPEC-4792

The code:

```
import logging.config

log_config = "logconfig.ini"
logging.config.fileConfig(log_config)
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

The logconfig.ini file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,sampleLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=sampleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_sampleLogger]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=sampleLogger
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=sampleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_sampleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

Comment: any thoughts on this?